# Why are the class tags for TF2 abbreviated?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are several tags for the different classes in Team Fortress 2, for example [tf2-spy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tf2-spy) and [tf2-medic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tf2-medic). Why is Team Fortress in the tag abbreviated? Written entirely does not go surpass the character limit.

Comment: Mea culpa. I quickly searched for it, but obviously with the wrong key words